# Инвертируется выделение текста | JS | CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Знает ли кто-нибудь, почему моё выделение так странно себя ведет? При выделении текста внутри section все ок, но если пытаться выделить что-то за пределами, особенно на границе двух секций, то выделение резко инвертируется. Это какая-то проблема в стилях?

**Стили родителя**

```
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: overlay;
```

Структура

```
root
    > section
        > message or date
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте `css + html` данной проблемы к вопросу.

Comment: Проверьте без `flex-direction: column-reverse;`

Comment: Полагаю Инквизитор прав - это из-за column reverse; Не советую вам его использовать, он сволочь не работает на мобильных устройствах. Если нужно поменять элементы местами - используйте transform: rotate(180deg); , а дочерним следовательно transform: rotate(-180deg); и будет вам счастье.